# Creating a list of objects from LINQ select new

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Why does the first linq query work, but the second one does not?

```
var locations =
    from routeLocation in db.Table<RouteLocation>()
    join location in db.Table<Location>() on routeLocation.LocationId equals location.Id
    where functionalLocation.RouteId == routeId
    select new Location() { Id = location.Id, ParentId = location.ParentId, 
                            Name = location.Name 
                          };


var locations =  
    from routeLocation in db.Table<RouteLocation>()
    join location in db.Table<Location>() on routeLocation.LocationId equals location.Id
    where functionalLocation.RouteId == routeId
    select new { Location = location };
```

The compiler error for the second query is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: Location Location>>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Location>

I tried declaring the var as a List of Location instead, but still get the same error. Is it possible for me to use the syntax in the second example, instead of having to specify each property as in the first example?

Comment: Error message is self explanatory!

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: `select new { ...}` instead of `select new Location { ...}`

Answer (score 1):

The second query creates a new anonymous type by `new {...}`. The type of `locations` is therefore an `IEnumerable` of this anonymous type which you`re probably trying to cast into a`List` which produces the shown error.

If you want to create a list of new `Location` objects, then you need to create a copy constructor in the class `Location` (i.e. a constructor with the signature `Location(Location location)` which copies all fields of the given `Location` into the new one. Then you can change your query to the following:

```
var locations =  
    from routeLocation in db.Table<RouteLocation>()
    join location in db.Table<Location>() on routeLocation.LocationId equals location.Id
    where functionalLocation.RouteId == routeId
    select new Location(location);
```

This yields an `IEnumerable<Location>` which can be converted to an `List<Location>` by means of the `ToList()` method.

Comment: 1. You don't *need* a copy constructor, it's perfectly fine to use object initialiser syntax as per the first example. 2. `ToList` doesn't give you an `IList`, it's a concrete `List`.

Comment: You're right about the return type of `ToList()`. I fixed that in the answer. You're also right about the initialiser syntax. However, I wouldn't rely on this but would always use a copy constructor. Otherwise, this distributes the copy semantics of the object over all places in the code that uses the initialiser syntax. The copy constructor keeps this encapsulated in one place. (In any case, I try to avoid copying reference-type objects as far as possible)

Comment: The point I am making is that you don't *need* one. Your answer implies this is a requirement rather than what you consider best practice.