# C# Lambda expression select new

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this lambda expression:

```
this.SitesStore.DataSource = 
dc.Sites.Where(s => multipleSites.Select(ms => ms.Siteid )
.Contains(s.Siteid) && s.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString())).ToList();
```

But I want to modify it with this `Select new` instead of `Select(ms => ms.Siteid)`:

```
Select new { s.Cid, s.Siteid, FullName = dc.fn_GetSiteid(int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString()), s.Siteid) + " - " + s.FullName, s.Title, s.Address, s.Phone }
```

if I just add this `Select new` I get this error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Ext.Net.Utilities.StringUtils.Contains(string, params string[])' has some invalid arguments

**multipleSites:**

```
var multipleSites = (from cs in dc.CUsersSites
                        join c in dc.CUsers on cs.UserId equals c.UserId
                        where cs.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString()) && c.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                        select cs).ToList();
```

**Schemas**

```
CUsersSites (id, UserId, Cid, Siteid)
CUsers (id, UserId, UserName)
Sites (id, Cid, Siteid, FullName)
```

Comment: And what didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a list of objects from LINQ select new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011605/creating-a-list-of-objects-from-linq-select-new)

Comment: Please show the exact code that didn't work. You can't just replace a method call with `Select new { ... }` but you *can* use `Select(ms => new {  ... })`

Comment: What you want ot acheive with that select? The `Contains` method should be used on and array, but your new `Select(s => new { ... })` returns an anonymous type objects array.

Comment: See the edit to my answer, does that work? Making some assumptions here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just need to add the `Select` with the correct syntax as @JonSkeet already mentioned. Furthermore, you can simplify and avoid the issue you are getting (mentioned in your edit) by using `Any(ms => ...)` instead inside of the `Where`.

Here is the full example.

```
this.SitesStore.DataSource = dc.Sites
    .Where(s => multipleSites.Any(ms => ms.Siteid == s.Siteid && s.Cid == int.Parse(Session["Cid"].ToString())))
    .Select(s => new { ... })
    .ToList();
```

So this should compile but some things to note:

- This assumes the type of `Cid` is `int`.
- It seems odd to me that you would need to call `ToString()` presuming the `Session[]` IS an array of strings. Conversely, if `Session` holds `int` already then there would be no need for `int.Parse(...)`.

Comment: Code dumps are not considered answers, please explain your code in the answer

Comment: The op wants to use that select instead of `Select(ms => ms.Siteid)`

Comment: Do they? The `Select` you mention is nested in the `Where` (predicate) and should be able to remain untouched.